# Messed up absolute positioned image on my page

Tags: html, xhtml, css

On this site I have an auto-resizing BG but I wanted a fixed black bar at the bottom of the page.

The site looks fine when the browser is maximized but when you scale the window down and scroll down the black bar almost completely gone and it looks messed up. It is not positioning correctly.

I have tried a few things but can't figure out a solution to this.  Does anybody have any ideas how I should go about this? (Maybe I am missing 1 little thing or maybe I need to start over from scratch, either way please help!)

Note: the auto size background is in the html tag and the black bottom bar is in its own separate div tag "#black_bottom"

http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/gm_2012/

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `height:100%` from `#black_bottom` make the `absolute:position div height auto`.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I knew I was over looking something simple!!

Comment: Actually that doesn't do the trick. when you make the browser thinner when you have to scroll to the side it doesn't fill the bottom 100%....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I see what you're going for now. If my understanding is correct, you want the gradient background to extend to about 70-73px above the bottom edge of your content box, where it meets the solid gray bar which extends to the bottom of the window, or just below that bottom circular G emblem, whichever is lower. I've accomplished this by **removing the `#black_bottom` element entirely**, setting a solid gray background color for the `html` element to match the color of your bottom bar graphic, and applied the circular gradient background to the `body` element. I've also removed the explicitly-defined height from `#wrapper`, and given it a negative `margin-bottom` to allow the black bar to underlap it. The styles I replaced are listed below. Hopefully this is closer to what you're after:

```
html {
    background: #333;
}

body {
    background: url(http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/gm_2012/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto -136px;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I just realized I forgot to add `z-index: -1` to `#black_bottom` and `position: relative;` to wrapper. I've edited the style definitions in my answer to include them. Also, you need to go into your HTML and make sure you're closing all your tags correctly. `#wrapper` is *inside* of `#black_bottom` and it should be *directly before* it.

Comment: *and also `min-height: 100%;` to `#wrapper`

Comment: It still doesn't work for me... The whole page isn't centered and the black bar doesn't show up at the bottom when I do this.

Comment: Alright, scratch that. Bear with me and try the solution I've edited into my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything wrapped incorrectly I believe. Why does your `<div id="black_bottom>` contain everything from your wrapper to your `<div id="footer_wrap">`?

Comment: At firts I didn't have it wrapping around everything but it wasn't showing up so I put it wrapping everything and it showed up.  I didn't understand why but it seemed to work so I went with it.

How could I fix this?